# How to add an "Organization Resource" to Google Cloud Platform in order to submit a paid tech-support case?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We've signed up for the "Silver" paid-support plan on Google Cloud, but when we try to submit a case, we get an error message saying that an "Organization Resource" needs to be created first. There's a "Learn More" link on the page, but it does not answer this.

We've tried using the "gcloud organizations list" command, but no organizations are listed. We'd be most grateful is someone is familiar with what needs to be done to submit a paid tech support case. Thank you!

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQlgk.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations), if you have a G Suite or Cloud Identity account at the moment you create a Google Cloud Platform project, the organization would be automatically created for you. Organizations are resources only available to those accounts (i.e. [G Suite account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53926) or [Cloud Identity account](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7319251?visit_id=637075071727671264-151366864&rd=1)).

It may also be helpful to check out how to [start using Organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations).